# Twitter Bootstrap to act in client MVC model

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, extjs, architecture

Newbie at web development, and about to choose tech for a new enterprise web app.
I understand that Bootstrap would be the most modern way to implement great UI.

Does it have (or is there some 3rd party) that can make its architecture to MVC in the client side like Extjs? I'm afraid all the data binding would be much trouble here...
And also make me write more declerative code and not so much in "html" style..

Comment: Use [`AngularJS`](https://angularjs.org/) for `MVC` implementation. You may also have a look at [`TypeScript`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) for more declarative syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a CSS Framework (Twitter Bootstrap). It hasn't got any plugin for doing the Data Binding. If you want to that this is a popular frameworks in nowadays:

- [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org)
- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

It has many different MVC Frameworks. I use AngularJS from Google. Simple and it has many features. I hope I can help for you.